# Null Error When using If statements to loop through specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I get error message of "Cannot enter a null value as an item or field name in a pivot table report"

```
   Sub loopthruallsheets()

    Dim Shts() As Variant
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet


   Shts = Array("1", "3", "5", "7")

 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 With Sheet
    If .Range("G2").Value = 1 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("N10:N11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("N14:N22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("N27:N29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 2 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("O10:O11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("O14:O22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("O27:O29").Value
        End If
     If .Range("G2").Value = 3 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("P10:P11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("P14:P22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("P27:P29").Value
        End If
     If .Range("G2").Value = 4 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("Q10:Q11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("Q14:Q22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("Q27:Q29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 5 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("R10:R11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("R14:R22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("R27:R29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 6 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("S10:S11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("S14:S22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("S27:S29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 7 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("T10:T11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("T14:T22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("T27:T29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 8 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("U10:U11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("U14:U22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("U27:U29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 9 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("V10:V11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("V14:V22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("V27:V29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 10 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("W10:W11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("W14:W22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("W27:W29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 11 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("X10:X11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("X14:X22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("X27:X29").Value
        End If
    If .Range("G2").Value = 12 Then
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range("Y10:Y11").Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range("Y14:Y22").Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range("Y27:Y29").Value

         End If
       End With
         Next Sheet
      End Sub
```

I need the code to copy and paste value in a specific place but with each different period (months1-12) its a different column of data. My code errors out at Period 4 ( which is my current period for our fiscal year)

Comment: Are you overwriting a pivot table? Btw you could get rid of all those IF statements using Offset.

Comment: What is `Shts = Array("1", "3", "5", "7")` for?  Your code takes cells on a sheet and copies them to new cells _on the same_ sheet.  Is that what you want for each of the 12 sheets?

Comment: I would change this to `Select Case`

Comment: Better than Select case would be use some index because the column are in order "N, O, P, Q, R, S..." and If's or Select case would be reduced to just few lines of code

Comment: @PGilm Shts = Array is the sheets I want the code to affect, (1,3,5,7) are the different sheets. I do not want every sheet to be affected. yes depending on what month were in i want the code to copy the data and paste value into another area of the sheet

Comment: Oh wow, good eye! @RafałB.

Comment: @jonathanmarin you have not coded that in here

Comment: @RafałB. & urdearboy how can i incorporate that to only affect certain sheets? my file has about 30 worksheets but i need it to work on about 23 of them

Comment: @jonathanmarin - An array is one way to do it.  Is there any logic as to *which* sheets you want to run this on? Or is it okay with you just to create an array of sheet indexes/sheet names?

Comment: @BruceWayne there is no logic to the sheets i want to use, I have sheet names but to keep the post short i changed the names to 1,3,5,7 etc.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real need to have that many `If` statements (or use `Select Case`).  This is just a pattern you can use with `Cells()` instead of just `Range()`:

```
Sub t()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim startCol As Long, celVal As Long, i As Long
Dim shts() As Variant

startCol = 13 ' 14 is Column M

shts = Array(1, 3, 5, 7)

For i = LBound(shts) To UBound(shts)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shts(i))
        celVal = .Range("G2").Value
        .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range(.Cells(10, startCol + celVal), .Cells(11, startCol + celVal)).Value
        .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range(.Cells(14, startCol + celVal), .Cells(22, startCol + celVal)).Value
        .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range(.Cells(27, startCol + celVal), .Cells(29, startCol + celVal)).Value
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

From your comment, I also tweaked the `For` loop to instead just loop through the specific sheets you want.  (I also assumed that `1, 3, 5, 7` are the sheet *indexes* you want to use, not actual sheet name.  If sheets are indeed named `1`, `3`, etc. then use `shts = Array("1", "3", "5", "7")`)

Comment: @jonathanmarin - Did that fix it for you? (If so, you can mark as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post)

Answer (score 0):

This is @BruceWayne answer with your array 1/3/5/7 - (names, not indexes)

```
 Sub loopthruallsheets()
 Dim Shts() As Variant
 Dim Sheet As Variant
 Dim startCol As Long
    startCol = 13 ' 13 is Column M
 Dim celVal As Long

 Shts = Array("1", "3", "5", "7")

 For Each Sheet In Shts
    With Worksheets(Sheet)
    celVal = .Range("G2").Value
    .Range("H10:H11").Value = .Range(.Cells(10, startCol + celVal), .Cells(11, startCol + celVal)).Value
    .Range("H14:H22").Value = .Range(.Cells(14, startCol + celVal), .Cells(22, startCol + celVal)).Value
    .Range("H27:H29").Value = .Range(.Cells(27, startCol + celVal), .Cells(29, 
  startCol + celVal)).Value
    End With
  Next Sheet
  End Sub
```